# dynamodb ConditionExpression in Step functions

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-step-functions

With the use of `aws-step-functions` I'm trying to `putItem` into `dynamodb`.

Here is an extract of the `.yml`, which works as intended.

```
...

AddingURLs:
  Type: Map
  ItemsPath: "$.vidPosts"
  Parameters:
    vidPostsIndex.$: "$$.Map.Item.Index" 
      vidPosts.$: "$$.Map.Item.Value"

  Iterator:
    StartAt: AddingURLIntoDynamoDB
    Comment: Looping over urls and adding them into the db

    States:
      AddingURLIntoDynamoDB:
        Type: Task
        Resource: arn:aws:states:::dynamodb:putItem
        ResultPath: null
        Parameters:
          TableName: my-table-table-name
          Item:
            videoID:
              S.$: "$.vidPosts.[0]"
            urls:
              S.$: "$.vidPosts.[1]"
          ConditionExpression: "attribute_not_exists(videoID)"    

        End: true

  Next: EndStepFunctions

EndStepFunctions:
  Comment: This marks the end of a step functions
  Type: Succeed
```

But the next time around, when this state is called, if it encounters an entry that already exists, because of, `ConditionExpression: "attribute_not_exists(videoID)"`, as it should, it throws,

```
{
  executionArn: 'arn:aws:states:us-east-2:aaabbbccc:execution:xxxStateMachine:XXX-YYY-ZZZ',
  stateMachineArn: 'arn:aws:states:us-east-2:aaabbbccc:stateMachine:xxxStateMachine',
  name: '9814ce93-bc42-4f31-a742-089ea7db9ad6',
  status: 'FAILED',
  startDate: 2021-03-18T15:30:45.912Z,
  stopDate: 2021-03-18T15:30:52.386Z,
  input: '{}',
  inputDetails: { included: true },
  error: 'DynamoDB.ConditionalCheckFailedException',
  cause: 'The conditional request failed (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ConditionalCheckFailedException; Request ID: bfd76f51-567b-439c-9a39-5a1643e75a69; Proxy: null)'
}
```

My question is within `aws-step-functions`, how do I make it ignore existing entries but continue with the iterator?

Appreciate any help and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We just need to catch `DynamoDB.ConditionalCheckFailedException` exception and move forward, without throwing any error.

What we need is

```
  "Catch": [
    {
      "ErrorEquals": [
        "DynamoDB.ConditionalCheckFailedException"
      ],
      "Next": "FinalStep"
    }
  ]
```

Here is full step function.

```
{
  "StartAt": "put-item",
  "States": {
    "put-item": {
      "Next": "FinalStep",
      "Catch": [
        {
          "ErrorEquals": [
            "DynamoDB.ConditionalCheckFailedException"
          ],
          "Next": "FinalStep"
        }
      ],
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::dynamodb:putItem",
      "Parameters": {
        "Item": {
          "pk": {
            "S": "1"
          },
          "test": {
            "S": "value"
          }
        },
        "TableName": "test",
        "ConditionExpression": "attribute_not_exists(#videoID)",
        "ExpressionAttributeNames": {
          "#videoID": "videoID"
        }
      }
    },
    "FinalStep": {
      "Type": "Pass",
      "End": true
    }
  }
}
```

Put-item failed with error and still moved to next task.

```
{
  "Error": "DynamoDB.ConditionalCheckFailedException",
  "Cause": "The conditional request failed (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ConditionalCheckFailedException; Request ID: xxxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxxxx; Proxy: null)"
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a few options here.

1. Don't put a condition on the `putItem`. If the data is the same then you can just allow it to override the data with the new data, which won't really change anything. Keep in mind that `putItem` is not the same as an SQL `INSERT`. It's more like an `UPSERT`.
2. Add a `Catch` block to your step and have it proceed to the same place as the success case. You may need to have it first go to a `Pass` state if you are expecting something from the output of the `putItem` to be in the input of the next step.
3. Add a step before the put that does a get and then do the put on a conditional step. This may not be the best option if there are cases where you could get multiple invocations for the same record within close proximity because you could have both hit the get and not see a record and then both would do a put (in which case one would fail). If you won't ever have that case then this would work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @JasonWadsworth. 1). It needs not to overwrite existing entries, therefore `putItem` along `ConditionalExpression` is required. 2).  I was trying to add a `Catch` to it but I was not able to get it right, but @BaluVyamajala below got it working exactly how it should be, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/66697620/789782 3). Instead of supplementing this with another solution, I was more looking for a true 100% `step-function` only solution

Comment: The 3rd option was still in Step Functions. You can call `getItem` on DynamoDB in a step function, and pass the results of that to the next step.